# SSL authentication error for Snow Client when trying to execute from command line

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the below error while trying to connect to Snowflake from Command line

SSL Certificate is invalid for sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com. The certificate chain is as follows:
1: Subject : Common Name: sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com.

Please assist and let me know how I can set it to noproxy. I have already tried by using the command snowsql set noproxy

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the error indicates there is a proxy which is intercepting Snowflake's SSL certificate and replacing with their own.  The best way to resolve this is to ensure the certificate is trusted in the proxy and/or the environment variables are configured as per our documentation so that the Snowflake certificate can pass through.

The error is often resolved by network configuration adjustments. Please confirm with your network/firewall teams if there is proxy and/or SSL proxy in place. One common issue is attributed to security intercepting Snowflake's SSL certificate and replacing with their own. The documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#using-a-proxy-server) has more information using a proxy with SnowSQL. The Snowflake documentation links along with the certificate error details are useful to pass along to a network engineer who can whitelist at least the below URLs (documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/clients-considerations.html#hostname-whitelisting) confirming the whitelisting requirements) in order to resolve the SnowSQL connection issue.

```
sfc-snowsql-updates.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443
ocsp.digicert.com:80
ocsp.msocsp.com:80
ocsp.snowflakecomputing.com:80
```

Source : https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Error-SSL-Certificate-is-invalid-for-URL-The-certificate-chain-is-as-follows